# Spring boot transaction in open session in view

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

By default Spring boot uses open session in view pattern.

Does it mean that each time method annotated with @Transactional uses the entity manager created at the beginning of the request or creates a new one each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction, unless with `REQUIRES_NEW` will re-use an existing thread bound  `EntityManager` or `Session` (depending if you use JPA or plain Hibernate). The open session in view, will open and bind one at the start of a request.

So it will reuse the current thread bound one.

For plain Hibernate you can check the [`SpringSessionContext` class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringSessionContext.java). For JPA this is a bit hidden in proxies, but you could check the [`EntityManagerFactoryUtils` class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java).